# Show that $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I've tried to show that $\mathbb N$ is an infinite set.

*Proof*. By contradiction: assume that exists a bijeciton $f$ from $\mathbb N$ to $I_n = \{1, \dots, n-1\}$. We know that $f{\restriction_{I_n}}$ is injective and its image is a proper subset of $I_n$. From here, we can show that, by restricting the codomain of $f{\restriction_{I_n}}$ to $f{\restriction_{I_n}}(I_n)$, we obtain a bijection from a proper subset of $I_n$, that is, $f{\restriction_{I_n}}(I_n)$, to $I_n$ itself. But this is a contradiction. $\square$

Is it a correct proof?

EDIT: I'm using Peano's definition for $\mathbb N$, where $I_n$ is the set $\{0, S(0), \dots, S^{n-1}(0)\}$. For *infinite set*, I mean a set for which there is no bijection between it and any $I_n$, $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: No. How do you know that the restriction of $f$ to $I_n$ gives a **proper** subset of $I_n$?

Comment: What's your definition on $\Bbb N $?

Comment: @user296602 Because we're assuming that $f: \mathbb N \to I_n$ is bijective, and we're restricting it to a proper subset of the domain; so $f{\restriction_{I_n}}(I_n)$ must be $\subsetneqq I_n$.

Comment: @krirkrirk Peano's definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your proof is correct.

Indeed, if $f\colon\Bbb N\to\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ is injective, then restricting the function to $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ would be an injection from a finite set into a proper subset, which is a contradiction to the pigeonhole principle.

One can argue in several other ways, e.g. using Peano axioms, or other axioms from which you can obtain (in a second-order) the natural numbers in a relatively natural way. These ways lend themselves to slightly different proofs. But your suggested proof is correct, and is a fairly standard proof in elementary set theory courses.

Comment: Isnt OP's proof clumsy since one could have $\Bbb N = I_n $?

Comment: In that case, what is $I_{n+1}$? As I wrote in the last paragraph, this really comes down to how you define $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Well $I_{n+1}=I_n $ leading to a contradiction (see my answer). Thus expliciting this actually proved the whole point

Comment: But you haven't answered my question. *What* is $I_{n+1}$? You need to give me a proper definition of $I_{n+1}$, and for that matter of "what is a natural number" before we can address the rest of your comment. Moreover, it might also depend on your definition of infinite. There is a lot at stake here, so being pedantic about definition is important.

Comment: OP uses Peano's definition and I suppose he meant $I_n = \{0, S (0), \dots, S^{n-1}(0)\} $ but only them can tell. Since you think their proof is right, I return the question?

Comment: Note that the proof you suggest also uses, implicitly the pigeonhole principle. There is no real way of avoiding it. It might be slightly simpler if you appeal only to $S$. But once you've got the pigeonhole principle, might as well use it for a quick proof, it doesn't eat any bread (as my complex analysis professor used to say).

Comment: Sure but OP's proof still seems clumsy : it only works if $\Bbb N \neq I_n $ and proving this is the case is proving the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

Why not proceed by contradiction by [Peano's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) assuming that $\mathbb N$ is finite and thus it should have a maximum $M$?

Answer (score 1):

I once learned that a set is infinite iff there exists an injection into a proper subset of itself, and this is pretty trivial for N. A mapping like n->(n+n) does what one wants, depending of course on what you know about N.

With less knowledge:
$f|I_n$ is injective (as restriction of bijective mapping), which means we have an injective mapping $f|I_n: I_n -> I_n$. Our friend $I_n$ is finite, hence the mapping is actually bijective. Which is already the contradiction, n+1 would have to be mapped to something in $I_n$ violating the injectivity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\Bbb N $ has cardinal $n $, then $$\begin {align}\Bbb N  &= \{0,S (0),... ,S^{n-1} (0)\}\\ &:= \{0,1,...,n-1\}\end{align}$$
Since $S(n-1) \in \Bbb N$, $\exists 0 <i \leq n-1$ such that $S(n-1) =  i $  and so $n-1=i-1$, contradicting that $\Bbb N $ has cardinal $n $.